# What is the fastest way to calculate rolling standard deviation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, vectorization

I have a dataset where I need to calculate rolling standard deviations and averages on group by basis.

```
Average_SP7 = dogs.groupby(by="name")["S"].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(7, 1).mean())

StdDevFin7 = dogs.groupby(by="name")["F"].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(7,1).std())
```

I know that in terms of it is advised against using transform and apply.

I manage to calculate the rolling average by using numpy convolution which speeds it up considerably.

```
grouped= df.groupby(by=grp_by)[attr]
s = [[], []]
for k, group in grouped:
    convolved_SP = np.convolve(group, np.ones(window_size))
    convolved_SP = convolved_SP[:-(window_size - 1)]
    divisor = np.ones(len(convolved_SP)) * window_size
    divisor[:min(len(divisor), window_size-1)] = np.arange(1, min(len(divisor) + 1, window_size))
    convolved_SP = convolved_SP / divisor
    s[0].extend(group.index)
    s[1].extend(convolved_SP)
return_s = pd.Series(s[1], index=s[0])
return_s.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Is is posible to do a rolling standard deviation with a vectorized approach. I know you need the rolling average for, so maybe I can build on my code.

The input:

```
                    F
name             
beg It xiam      11.0
beg It xiam      12.0
beg It xiam      13.0
beg It xiam       7.0
beg It xiam       5.5
```

The rolling standard deviation for the name "beg It xiam".

```
                        F
name                 
beg It xiam           NaN
beg It xiam      0.707107
beg It xiam      1.000000
beg It xiam      2.629956
beg It xiam      3.271085
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output

Comment: Ok, I added an example, I know how to calculate anyway, I just want to speed it up.

Comment: Is `df.groupby("name").F.rolling(7, min_periods=1).std()` fast enough?

Comment: What's `.F` @MustafaAydın

Comment: @Vishnudev Alternative syntax for `["F"]`.

Comment: Ohh. Misinterpreted it. I thought it is something like `.T` tranform.

Comment: @MustafaAydın It is faster no doubt. Though the problem is that it is not ordered like transform.

Comment: @BorutFlis You can pass `sort=False`: `df.groupby("name", sort=False).F.rolling(7, min_periods=1).std()` (which also should make it slightly faster).